# How to synchronize time between two devices on a local network using NTPD, with one device serving as both client and server on separate interfaces?

Tags: dhcp, local-area-network, ntp, time-synchronization, ntpd

I am using STM32MP1 based two devices which runs on Yocto Linux platform. Among them one has two network interfaces (wlan0, wlan1) where wlan0 is used for connecting with internet servers & wlan1 will be acting as host network for another device to connect with this. I am using `ntpd` (version: ntpd 4.2.8p13@1.3847) for Time Synchronization.
I had a common `ntp.conf` for both devices.

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
server 127.127.1.0
fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 14
restrict default
```

Also DHCP client configuration also same for both devices.

```
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
        domain-name, domain-name-servers, host-name,
        netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope;
```

And neither I didn't have the specific servers mentioned in `ntp.conf` file nor my device's DHCP client is not requesting `ntp-servers` explicitly. But still my primary device (which has two network interfaces) can able to sync with Time servers which my Wi-Fi router provides.

But my secondary device can't get time sync understandably it can't reach time servers directly. The issue is the primary device is not acting as NTP server (on wlan1) for the secondary device to get timesync. I have used `udhcpd` on primary device for the secondary device to connect, below is the `udhcpd.conf` used,

```
start 192.168.10.100
end 192.168.10.200
interface wlan1
option subnet 255.255.255.0
option router 192.168.10.1
option lease 43200
option dns 192.168.10.1
option domain local
```

## Questions:

1. Will NTPD work as both a server (on one interface) and a client (on another interface) on the same device?
2. If yes means how to achieve that within local network without internet for the secondary device?
3. If no means what is the reason & how to overcome that to get timesync for the secondary device?

Answer (score 1):

> Will NTPD work as both a server (on one interface) and a client (on another interface) on the same device?

Yes. The *default* mode of ISC NTPD is to be both a client and a server. The fact that there's two interfaces is not relevant; the operating system handles routing.

> If yes means how to achieve that within local network without internet for the secondary device?

Set the devices to use your internet facing device as NTP server. Configure firewalls to allow this traffic.

Comment: Just add a line with `server ip iburst`. Also, `man ntpd.conf` will show you more details. No reason to have a `restrict` directive for the upstream server.

Comment: After doing the changes my devices ntp.conf look like this,  
**Primary Device**  
`driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift  
server 127.127.1.0  
fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 14  
restrict default  
restrict 192.168.10.0 mask 255.255.255.0 nomodify notrap`  
**Secondary Device**  
`driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift  
server 192.168.10.1 iburst  
server 127.127.1.0  
fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 14  
restrict default`  

After making changes, I did a reboot still the secondary device time is not getting synced with primary device, why?

Comment: Possibly a firewall? https://docs.ntpsec.org/latest/debug.html

Comment: Actually I can see 123/udp port is accessible for NTP services in `cat /etc/services` also below is the netstat output from primary device.
`root@stm32mp1-disco:/etc# netstat -tuln | grep 123
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 ::1:123                 :::*
udp        0      0 :::123                  :::*`

Answer (score 0):

`If yes means how to achieve that within local network without internet for the secondary device?`

GPS is very common for time synchronization. Many data centers have these.

https://timemachinescorp.com/product/gps-time-server-tm1000a/